# Will I lose private repositories shared with me if I change my GitHub username?

Tags: github

I'm thinking on changing my GitHub username but I'm afraid of losing access to private repositories I have access to. Is there any problem if I change it? When trying to change username there is a warning massage as follows,
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **Name**, the simple answer is no it won't change your repositories and you can remove or edit your name at any time,
[image]

For **Username**, the answer is also no but if you want to change the username it is a different story, all data and all links which are directing to your user profile will be gone if you are changing the username. But as mentioned in your question **private repositories won't be gone**. Personally, I don't recommend to change the username.

Comment: But what about the username?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [the official documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-personal-account-settings/changing-your-github-username) to help others:

> After changing your username, your old username becomes available for anyone else to claim. Most references to your repositories under the old username automatically change to the new username. However, some links to your profile won't automatically redirect.